# How to bulk change more then 500 issues at the time in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

We are using SonarQube 5.1.1 and are analyzing some old legacy projects.

The problem is that we get a huge number of issues and would like to bulk change all of them as False/Positive and start from zero issues so we only get new issues and old ones that pop up again.

Is there a way to bulk change more then the basic 500 issues? If not in the web UI which tables in the database do we need to modify except the issues table?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of the current architecture. It should be addressed [in a near future](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6638).

Note that direct manipulation of the database is not recommended, this will introduce inconsistencies and make your instance unusable (especially due to the use of ElasticSearch for issues since SonarQube 5.0).